# Using 60 fps footage on 23.976 sequence without slowing down or dropping frames

Tags: premiere, adobe, framerate, filming, adobe-media-encoder

I just recorded a 4k 60 fps clip from my GoPro and dropped it with some other clips on a timeline which is 23.976 fps, and the 60 fps clip looks really weird and glittery.

Is there a way to play this real time without dropping frames? I'm using Adobe Premiere Pro.

Comment: Remember that the preview you see when editing is not the same as what gets exported at the end. Try exporting a test to see how it looks at full quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not. You have contradicting parameters.

You need to make some decisions. Either:

- Leave your project at 29.97 and drop 1 every 2 frames of your 60fps clip.
- Leave your project at 29.97 and use all the frames of the 60 fps clip making it slow-motion 2x.
- Change the project speed to 60fps and render twice every frame of the other footage.
- Change the project speed to 60fps and make a timewarp filter on the 29.97 footage, what it does is inventing new pixels to the new frames, making it look smoother if the program used is a good one.
- Preparing separated projects and making a strange arrangement of projectors projecting two framerates at some cinema screen... Nop, let us discard this idea and just keep the other 4 in mind.

Comment: Indeed, a very clear answer! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Set your sequence to 60fps.

Comment: Thanks! But no! There are some clips in the timeline which is in 23.976fps. So, they will look weird.

Comment: I'm really new to Video Editing. I'm not even sure if what I asked is against Video Editing principals. So if higher framerate is added to a lower framerate timeline, the only solution to play them realtime is dropping frames. Right?